# Detecting focussed control in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, focus, updatepanel

I have an update panel which is causing a postback on part of the page and after postback the control that had focus (which is not in the update panel) loses focus. How can I identify which control had focus and save that value, so that I can refocus to it when the page reloads. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First I bind the focus on all input and keep the last focused control ID. Then after the UpdatePanel finish the load, I set the focus to the last one

```
// keep here the last focused id
var LastFocusedID = null;

function watchTheFocus()
{
  // on every input that get the focus, I grab the id and save it to global var
  $(":input").focus(function () {
     LastFocusedID = this.id;
  });   
}

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();    
prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {      
}

// after the updatePanel ends I re-bind the focus, and set the focus
//  to the last one control
function EndRequest(sender, args) {
    if(LastFocusedID != null)
        $('#' + LastFocusedID).focus();        
    watchTheFocus();
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{       
    watchTheFocus();
});
```

The only think is that I use jQuery to make it, but I present here my idea, you can make it with little more code with out jQuery.

Comment: I'm not using jQuery yet and I'm weak at java script so if you could give a detailed example without jQuery it could be very helpful and very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @DovMiller The only jQuery that you need to check is the $(":input").focus(), what is do is to add a function on the focus trigger of the input. All the rest are simple javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can get what element has focus with javascript using the `activeElement` and `hasFocus`property to `HTMLDocument` object.
It might not be supported by all since it's HTML5.

Comment: Where and how do I do that, in the aspx page or the c# code behind? What about regular html?

Comment: You could have a hidden input field "focusedControl". Before the client POST the form, you put the activeElement ID into the input. When you send back the page to the client, you set a javascript event `<body onload="init();">` where you search in the DOM for the ID and focus the control.

Comment: Can you please give a detailed example? It could be very helpful and will appreciated very much. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve like this

```
var last_focused = null;

$(function () {

 //store last focused element.

 $("input").live("focus", function(){
   last_focused = $(this);
 });


});

//in Script manager

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_pageLoaded(pageLoaded);

function pageLoaded(sender, args)
{
  if(last_focused != null) 
  {
    last_focused.focus();
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that in javascript? Where is the script manager code placed. Sorry for the ignorance I'm weak at javascript.

Comment: Yes it is javascript.It is Microsoft product of jquery for asp.net.Here also some events will trigger like page_load as you can see in asp.net.When update panel updated, this function will call automatically.For more Info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163354.aspx

Comment: More explanation and details of where in script and/or code this should be written could be helpful. Thank you.